# How should I license my source code?

Tags: license-recommendation, software-use

I have written a commercial application which contains closed source code and a script API which is open source. Currently I have a [CLA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contributor_License_Agreement) similar to [this](https://cla.developers.google.com/about/google-individual) which has to be signed by each contributor to be able to make changes/updates to the script API. However I'm not quite sure under which license I should release the public script API source code? The code belongs to me (copyright) but users should be able to use the code to design and distribute plugins for free or commercially, however I would like some legal protection in case someone decides to use the script API code and turn it into something evil/illegal/copyright infringement.

My question is if there already exists a license which suits my demands?

Comment: Wait, so will plugins to the Script API be independent? For example, will the only thing that I do to the API will be calling it's methods like `ScriptAPI.foo();`?

Comment: Define "evil," please.

Comment: @Kevin sharks with lasers on their heads 

Answer (score 0):

You can't really stop people from doing something "evil" with your code. However, most licenses carry a 'warranty' statement disclaiming any liability for damages that your program may cause, which may very well be caused by someone using your Script API for evil.

To distance yourself even further from bad actors, the [BSD-3 License](https://opensource.org/licenses/BSD-3-Clause) has this clause:

> Neither the name of the copyright holder nor the names of its contributors may be used to endorse or promote products derived from this software without specific prior written permission.

Preventing people from using your name to endorse their evil activities seem like a good way to get some legal protection as well.